# Software raid and filesystem

Tags: filesystems, raid, software-raid

What is the relation between software RAID and a file system?

Are they related?

Should I use a file system when I am using software RAID or I can access raided disk for RAW read and write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software RAID is a type of [RAID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_array_controller) which operates solely in software, with hardware only for the physical storage device interconnects, using the computer's own processing power (CPU, RAM, etc.) for everything relating to RAID. This is in contrast to a hardware RAID controller, which have their own cache memory, possibly backup battery, processor, etc. for the purpose of performing the work related to RAID. Since software RAID uses the computer's CPU, RAM etc. to perform its work, software RAID places an additional load on the computer that is not present with hardware RAID solutions.

[RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID), in turn,

> is a data storage virtualization technology that combines multiple physical disk drive components into a single logical unit for the purposes of data redundancy, performance improvement, or both.

In other words, it is a technology that allows you to combine multiple physical storage devices into a single logical storage device, for improved reliability, capacity (curiously not mentioned by Wikipedia's summary) and/or performance. The combined "array", as it is called, is then exposed to the operating system in much the same way as a regular hard disk and can be partitioned, formatted and used just as you would a regular disk.

A [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) is a way for the computer to know where on a disk data is located. File systems have a number of important aspects, but that which is most visible to the user is that they allow you to use memorable names and directory structures instead of needing to remember the sector numbers and sizes of each and every file yourself. This makes it possible to name a file "My PhD thesis.odt" and not have to worry about its location and size on disk, instead of needing to remember that your PhD thesis begins at block 505531735 and is 203429 bytes long. (The situation would get even more complex once you start worrying about fragmentation of on-disk data.)

On fixed storage, such as hard disks, file systems are commonly created on top of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning), which are logical subdivisions of a physical disk. In many cases a disk contains only a single partition covering the entire disk, but this need not be the case. Floppy disks and CDs are usually not partitioned, and some hard disks might not be partitioned (though this latter is the exception).

When we put all this together, at the bottom we have storage devices that actually hold the bits, then perhaps a RAID controller (in hardware or software), then partitions, then file systems, and then the files that you are actually interested in storing on the computer. Thus, with the physical storage hardware on top, the stack looks like:

- Physical storage device(s)
- RAID, if applicable
- Partition(s)
- File system
- Files

As you can see, file systems are highly useful; and if RAID is used, it is very much distinct from the file system. **It is possible to run a storage solution that does not include a file system, regardless of whether you are using RAID or not,** but because of the value added by file systems in general use, that is very rarely done. (A major exception is something like a Unix-like operating system's [swap partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems), but swap space still needs some form of record-keeping to know, for example, which memory pages belong to which processes and which portions of the swap space are free or in use. This can be considered a special-purpose file system.)

vic mentioned [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) which combines the RAID and file system into an integrated volume management solution while largely removing the need for manual partitioning, but ZFS is pretty much the exception in this regard.

Comment: [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) is another filesystem that has built-in RAID-like functionality, like ZFS.

Comment: @Wyzard Yes, but Btrfs, while interesting, is still nowhere near as stable as ZFS. For that matter, I think [ReFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS) offers similar functionality too. Of these, I do believe that it's safe to say that the only one which is in reasonably wide use outside of experimental setups is ZFS.

Comment: Hi Michael, nice answer! I just don't understand your remark about storage solutions not requiring a file system. How would you keep track of the stored files?

Comment: @vic Basically, you can't. That's the job of *some form* of file system, even if it is something trivial like a CD's table of contents, a compressed file's index or the swap usage bookkeeping I mentioned in the answer. That doesn't mean a file system is *required*, however, only that it is incredibly useful in practical use. Consider that the file system itself is just data; there is nothing magical about what a file system does, or the data that is stored within the file system's own data structures. With enough determination, you could do its job all on your own, but nobody is that crazy.

Comment: Ok but then I don't know why you _emphasized_ in your answer that a file system is not required. As you say yourself, you still need some possibility to reference files which can only be achieved if you use a file system or create one from scratch.

Comment: @vic I emphasized that because the OP specifically asked if it was possible to use a RAID array without a file system. That is *possible* in just the same way as using a single storage device without a file system is *possible*.

Comment: @vic a storage system can be useful not only for storing files. For instance you could install a database (Oracle has this option) that access the storage system directly. In this case the high level objects are not files but tables, indexes and so on.

Comment: @edc65 That's interesting, I didn't know this exists.

Comment: Hi @Michael, tnx for your elaboration, well done, low score for public up vote however, just to clarify, you mentioned that raided hard disks will become a single logical drive, but what if I want to access my raided drives with their physical address?(I want to use CreateFile in MSVC to have access to whole hard drive)

Comment: @hessamhedieh I don't know how the [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API function works with RAIDed devices. If you want to know whether a specific API call allows accessing a device in a specific way, refer to the vendor's (Microsoft's, in this case) documentation, or ask on [so] if the documentation doesn't give you the answer you need. Questions purely relating to programming are off topic on Super User and should be asked on Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

Soft RAID just gives you a way to abstract multiple devices, usually disks, into a single virtual device. You still need a file system in order to use the disk space of this virtual disk.

ZFS is a well-known exceptional case that incorporates both a type of RAID volume manager and a file system under one roof.

You can find a good overview on Soft Raid on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_RAID#Software-based)

Answer (score 1):

Software raid lets you arrange multiple block devices (or multiple partitions on a single block device) in a flexible configuration without the need of a hardware raid card.
For example, if you have two disks of 500GBs each,
then you can create a single volume of 1TB (stripped/concatenated) and use that for a filesystem which sees this as a single device of 1 TB worth of space.
Alternatively, you can create a single mirrored volume of size 500 GB and the software raid will take care of mirroring every write on both the underlying disks. The filesystem will see a single disk of size 500 GB.
There are more raid configs available.

A filesystem is an abstraction over a block device which lets you arrange your data in directories and files, a filesystem just needs a block device under it to store all the data in blocks and on on the upper layer it converts those data blocks into directories and files. A filesystem usually does not care about the the RAID level being used for the underlying block device.